# What is the multi-label limit for BERT based Hugging Face API?

Tags: huggingface-transformers

I'm totally new to the Hugging Face API and I'm trying to figure out the number of labels I can pass in a single API call. The reason I ask this is I tried using 5 labels some time back and it was giving me an error, but now when I tried with 40 labels it worked perfectly fine. So is there a limit at all for the number of labels in the multi-label approach?

The code is as follows-

```
 payload = json.dumps(
    {"inputs": corpus
    ,"parameters": {"candidate_labels": keywords, "multi_class": True}
    })

headers = {
    'Authorization': ':)',
    'Content-Type': 'application/json'
}
api_response = requests.request("POST", API_URL, headers=headers, data=payload)
```

Thank You!

Comment: Can you please share more details? The code that produced the error, the error that you got. Theoretically it has no limit on number of labels.

Comment: I'm getting gateway timeout and service unavailable messages @AshwinGeetD'Sa